# Using CSS print media with Xporability/css-to-pdf

Tags: css, css-to-pdf

I'm using https://github.com/Xportability/css-to-pdf to load HTML tables into a PDF. All is working fine except for being able to insert page breaks between the tables. Using this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>XEPjqPlugin</title> 
   <style>
       @media print {
           .noprint {display:none;}
           .print {width:100%; display:table-header-group;}
           body, article {width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 10pt; font-family:'Times New Roman',Times,serif;}
           table { page-break-after: always;}
       }
   </style>
   <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/xepOnline.jqPlugin.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="report">
        <div id="tablePage">
           <input class="noprint" name="tablepage" type="checkbox">
               <a class="noprint nodec" id="printit" href="#"
                   onclick="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('tablePage',{pageMargin:'0.5in'});"
                   ><img src="css/Images/button-print.png" />
           <div>
                <table id="table1" border="1">
                   <tr>
                        <th>Column 1</th>
                        <th>Column 2</th>
                        <th>Column 3</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2">Row 1 Cell 1</td>
                        <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td><td>Row 1 Cell 3</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td>Row 2 Cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 2 Cell 3</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">Row 3 Cell 1</td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
           </div>
           <div>
                <table id="table2" border="1">
                   <tr>
                        <th>Column 1</th>
                        <th>Column 2</th>
                        <th>Column 3</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2">Row 1 Cell 1</td>
                        <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td><td>Row 1 Cell 3</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td>Row 2 Cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 2 Cell 3</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">Row 3 Cell 1</td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

The @media print style isn't having any effect. The .noprint and page-break have not effect.

Comment: Can you post a link to your sample? I did things a bit different and copied the HTML in this page: http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Demos.TestSummerNote and added a "page-break-before" on the second div and it works fine.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce this problem and am working on a solution.  As a workaround, moving the stylesheet rules to an external stylesheet works.  Thanks, and will follow up.

Comment: I tried editing the code down to something short, all inclusive and that would illustrate the problem since I can't provide a link and aren't familiar with creating a fiddle. The actual app has external styles. Kevin, what exactly did you do differently to get the page break to work?

Comment: OK, I worked with user kstubs and we set up your example. We noted that the JS in question was not processing @media print directives that were in a "style" tag. We fixed the JS and updated GITHUB. Test again please as you say your styles are external and this has always worked.

Comment: I note you do not have a closing "a" tag above and I believe that is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update to the source has been posted.  There was a bug reading the embeded @media style from the current document.  I've tested this issue and it is now resolved.  For future bug reports, please report in Git.  Thanks.  Git project located here:  https://github.com/Xportability/css-to-pdf

Comment: I added a fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/503rdexa/1/ That fiddle seems to work the way you want it.

Comment: I should also note two things and I do not know which of the two fixed. I will leave to you to test. (1) You had an "a" tag in your source you never closed, and (2) you seemed to have some conflicting/repeating @media print rules on the body, div. I removed both of those and it worked. I can go back and test, but I am pretty confident it was the unclosed "a" tag.

Comment: And one additional note, while I posted a "fiddle" it ain;t the best environment to test such things. you should test in your environment as because fiddle uses iframes all over these things are searched for the content in question. The performance of the overall application as well as the results can suffer from all of the iframes on the page.

Comment: @KevinBrown I need to download the SVG with the table below it

Comment: @KevinBrown what srctype will be i use for it ?